# Refactor/rename steps to fix ""com.google" is restricted"" error

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

When I attempt to upload my apk then everytime I get the following error:
"Upload error
UPLOAD NEW APK TO PRODUCTION
Upload failed
You need to use a different package name because "com.google" is restricted."

When I rename or refactor based on the multiple different steps suggested on this site to change "com.google.samples.apps.myapp" it breaks the program in a manner which then prevents it from a successful "build"

I have read and reread: ["com.example restricted" Google Play error; even when changing the package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185964/com-example-restricted-google-play-error-even-when-changing-the-package-name)  AND also
[Android Studio Rename Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

I suspect that the refactor does not correct the links I need to the R file?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Android Studio / Gradle you don't need to change your package name (as it impacts your resources) but only the "applicationId" which is whats used for publishing.

Details here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

Comment: My bad, I was overthinking it.  I just changed the applicationId and nothing else and that fixed my problem.  I only changed the build.gradle file labled "module:app"  I did not touch the manifest.  I then ran clean project then rebuilt it.  So I don't know what files might have changed after building it but I don't think the manifest was modified from that.  Anyways it worked.  Saved me 25 I was going to pay guru.  Thanks again.